# Animating a number of lines linking pairs of objects in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to put together a match activity where word in one column are linked by a line to definitions in another column. Once all words have been linked to their definitions, you end up with a series of crossing lines so, so I want the definitions and their line to move so that each is level with their connected word and the lines have unravelled. I've got as far as connecting the words to their definitions using a line (as a sprite) and the definitions can then be moved using tweenlite -but I have no idea how I move the lines with their definition. Here is a much simplified section of code to give you an idea of what I am trying to do

```
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*; 

var wordArray:Array = [word1, word2, word3, word4];
var definitionArray:Array = [definition1, definition2, definition3,definition4];

for (var i:int = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++){
var line:Sprite = new Sprite();
line.graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000);
line.graphics.moveTo(wordArray[i].x, wordArray[i].y);
line.graphics.lineTo(definitionArray[i].x, definitionArray[i].y);   
this.addChild(line);
}

for (var j:int = 0; j < wordArray.length; j++){
    TweenLite.to(definitionArray[j], 2, {delay:1, y:wordArray[j].y});
}
```

I am new to this so any help on how I would animate the lines to they follow the definitions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, it got me started - the errors occur because when onUpdate occurs, TweenLite needs to know the type of the arguments that are passed to the function. What I did was to call to a separate function and use onUpdateParams: to specify the nature of the arguments passed. Here is the code:

```
TweenLite.to(definitionArray[i], 3, {y:wordArray[j].y,onUpdate:refreshLines,
                onUpdateParams:[lines,wordArray,definitionArray]});
```

with the function

```
function refreshLines(param1:Array,param2:Array,param3:Array):void{
    for (var j:int = 0; j < param4.length; j++){
        param1[j].graphics.clear();
        }
    for (var i:int = 0; i < param4.length; i++)
        {
        param1[i].graphics.lineStyle(2,0x000000);
        param1[i].graphics.moveTo(param2[i].x, param2[i].y);
        param1[i].graphics.lineTo(param3[i].x, param3[i].y);
        }
     }
```

Once again, many thanks for pointing me in the right direction, it saved me heaps of time.